# How to assign C# variable to CSS class variable in ASP.NET MVC ActionLink

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic-css

In the ActionLink code below, how can I assign a C# string variable to `@class` in the view in ASP.NET MVC 5?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage List", "Index", new { @class = "DynamicClassName" });
```

I want to replace the static string  `@class = "DynamicClassName"` with something dynamic, similar to `@class = @myChangingColorClass`

```
// Error 
// yes, myChangingColorClass is declared C# valid string 
@Html.ActionLink("Manage List", "Index", new { @class =  @myChangingColorClass });
```

Comment: Where do you declare `myChangingColorClass` exactly?

Comment: @ekad in the CSHTML view , there is no error, and viewing it in the debugger seems fine. Should I create the declaration code block right inside the new code block?

Comment: How and where is `myChangingColorClass ` declared? What's the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be do by two ways one is by setting value in ViewModel class or by setting value in ViewBag, ViewData or TempData.

Way 1) Preffered way Strongly Typed: Set css class name to viewmodel class attribute:

```
Class Student
{
  public ID BIGINT {get; set;}
  ... //other properties

}

Class StudentViewModel : Student
{
   public CssClass string {get; set;}
}
```

//controller action

```
public ActionResult Index(){
  StudentViewModel objModel; 
  //initialize model

  objModel.CssClass = "myCssClass"; //set css class name to viewmodel 
  return View(objModel);
}
```

//in view use code like below:

```
@model namespace.StudentViewModel;
@Html.ActionLink("Manage List", "Index", new { @class =  Model.CssClass })
```

Way 2) Set css class name to viewbag / viewdata / tempdate. But this is not prefered.

//controller action

```
public ActionResult Index(){

  ViewBag.CssClass = "myCssClass"; //set css class name to ViewBag
  //or
  ViewData["CssClass"] = "myCssClass"; //set css class name to ViewData
  //or
  TempData["CssClass"] = "myCssClass"; //set css class name to TempData

  return View();
}
```

//in view use code like below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage List", "Index", new { @class =  @ViewBag.CssClass })
//Or
@Html.ActionLink("Manage List", "Index", new { @class =  @Convert.toString(ViewData["CssClass"]) })
//Or
@Html.ActionLink("Manage List", "Index", new { @class =  @Convert.toString(TempData["CssClass"]) })
```

Please let me know, is this works for you?

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare `myChangingColorClass` in a code block in cshtml as below

```
@{
    string myChangingColorClass = "myClass";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting a string variable (property) in your **Model** or **ViewModel** class and then just set it from code-behind and use it in your view like this :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage List", "Index", new { @class =  @Model.myChangingColorClass});
```

Comment: Answer should be in detail, it adds knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    string myChangingColorClass = "myClass";
}

@Html.ActionLink("Manage List", "Index", null, new { @class = @myChangingColorClass });
```

it will generate

```
<a class="myClass" href="/ControllerName">Manage List</a>
```

but using this,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage List", "Index", new { @class = @myChangingColorClass });
```

it will generate

```
<a href="/ControllerName?class=myClass">Manage List</a>
```

it assumes it like a parameter of that method.. that u don't want..

add  `null` before `new { @class = @myChangingColorClass }` will solve this problem